# Replace ID according to value in another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 id  ver   name  order
'1', '0', 'John',  '1'
'2', '0', 'Jill',  '2'
'3', '0', 'Tania', '3'
'4', '0', 'susan', '5'
'5', '0', 'sam',   '6'
'6', '0', 'Josh',  '7'
'7', '0', 'Jane', '10'
'8', '0', 'Jade', '11'
'9', '0', 'Ane',  '8'
'10', '0', 'Ant', '4'
```

Now I need to arrange in a way that "order" is sequentially arrange such as this

```
 id  ver   name  order
'1', '0', 'John',  '1'
'2', '0', 'Jill',  '2'
'3', '0', 'Tania', '3'
'4', '0', 'Ant',   '4'
'5', '0', 'susan', '5'
'6', '0', 'sam',   '6'
'7', '0', 'Josh',  '7'
'8', '0', 'Ane',   '8'
'9', '0', 'Jane', '9'
'10', '0', 'Jade', '10'
```

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Based on your data it seems like a simple `update table_name set order=id;`. Look for row_number window_function

Comment: Ah I forgot to add one important condition that the name and order set as name shouldn't change the order value.

Comment: Is id on your table auto_increment ?

Comment: Yes it is auto increment.

Comment: Please post your table schema.

Comment: I can't post the schema, but the table looks very similar to what I have above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this resolve your problem.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET id = order;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was my first approach, but I have issue with duplicate id.